# Resizing window does not apply to JQuery functions - requires window refresh

Tags: jquery

I am designing a responsive website and there are some JQuery functions that need to adapt to the resizing of the site window. However, for some reason some functions do not adjust.

This is an example of a function:

```
function navigate(bottom, top, topbottom, position) {
            $(document).on("mouseleave", top, function() {
                if ($(bottom).is(':visible')) {
                } else {
                    $(bottom).show();
                }
                if ($(bottom).is(":hover")) {
                } else {
                    $(bottom).hide();
                }
            });
            $(document).on("mouseleave", bottom, function() {
                if ($(top).is(":hover")) {
                } else {
                    $(bottom).hide();
                }
            });

            var width = $(window).width();
            if (width <= 768) {
                $(document).on("mouseover", top, function() {
                    var top_2 = 50;
                    $(bottom).show();
                    $(".bottom_navigation").css({"top": top_2 * (position + 1)})
                });
            } else if (width > 768) {
                $(document).on("mouseover", top, function() {
                    var left = $(top).width();
                    $(bottom).show();
                    $(".bottom_navigation").css({"left": left * position})
                });
            }
        }
```

And I also tried something like this:

```
    $(window).on("resize", function() {
       //function here!

    });
```

Can anyone come up with an explanation so that I can understand this phenomenon and possibly come up with a solution?

Comment: Have you declared function in your code?

Comment: Yes I have, thank you!